# How to sort images in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18156/  I want images on right side have same height like image on left side and also that is not space between those images. I also have problem that vertical scroll appears. Any suggestion?

```
  <section class="learn_more">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
            <img src="`http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpg`" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
            <img src=`"http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpgg`" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
            <img src=`"http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpgg`" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: you can specify a height for your images using css... but if you have two cols/images with different width and want the images to be the same height while having no space between them, then you can't keep the original aspect ratio for one of the images. to remove the space between the images, you would need to overwrite the margin of the `col-` classes.

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_elia/DTcHh/18161/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i think you need.

First use this JS that will add same height of the element

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    equalHeight($(".same-height"));
});
```

Second first element has to have background image with cover like this 
**CSS**

```
.left-image{
   background: url('http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

After that wrap all html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="backgrounds-images">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 same-height left-image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 same-height">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpg" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <img  class="img-responsive" src="http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpg" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18164/

The most important is that first element has to have background image, only this way you can make it like you want

p.s
Nadam se da sam pogodio sta ti treba :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a very easy and the bootstrap way of achieving this would be create two rows instead of one, to control the height of the images.

```
             |
(row1)img1   |   (row1)img2
             |
             |
             |
(row2)blank  |   (row2)img3
             |
             |
```

The trick is - on the second row first col, leave it blank. So the HTML would look like

```
<section class="learn_more">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <img src="http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <img src="http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpgg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
<!--  2nd row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <!-- Leave this empty -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <img src="http://opusteno.rs/slike/desktop-pozadine/21289/slike-lava-desktop-t01.jpgg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Secondly, the gap in between the images is because of the padding each `.col-xx-` classes bring. So you could just remove the padding targeting the `.col-` classes or you could add a separate class of your own and use that custom class. You need to just add this to your CSS

```
.col-md-6, .col-sm-6, .col-xs-6 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[The updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18158/)

Comment: i think the op wants the height only like https://jsfiddle.net/o9kLub4p/ but dont quote me on that

Comment: Hmm sry but I don't think that's what he is looking for. @None - may be you could give us a rough picture of what you want in your question, to avoid confusion ?

Comment: what does that mean @none ?? " I want images on right side have same height like image on left side"

Comment: haha. It's the User's name who posted it . lol. Scroll up and have a look.